# How to zoom a UIImageView within a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView within a UIScrollView and I can vertically scroll, but not horizontal scroll because of how I set the content size. That's exactly how I want.

However, I can't seem to zoom in and out. I set the minimum and maximum zoom scale, but it's not working.

Can someone tell me why?

Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];

    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] ];
    tempImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0  ;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = tempImageView.image.size.width / self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    self.scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:tempImageView];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement the following delegate method for zooming:

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}
```

and make sure that you add `self.imageView` to your `self.scrollView` instead.
It should look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] ];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0  ;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = self.imageView.image.size.width / self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];
}
```

Comment: you are right, I changed it but it still did not work :(

Comment: thanks it worked perfectly. One last question, what is the purpose of self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES since I commented it out and it still scrolls fine?

Comment: Well that's for disabling scrolling if you wanted to disable scrolling dynamically. You don't need it because you want it to scroll. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69562/discussion-between-pangu-and-armin-m).

Answer (score 2):

To get zooming to work, you need to provide a delegate method that returns the view you wish to get zoomed:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   return self.imageView
}
```

You will also need to hold on assign `tempImageView` to a property so that you can refer to it here. If you don't want to hang on to it in a property, you will need some other way of identifying the view, e.g. `scrollView.subviews[0]` if it is the only subview.

Answer (score -1):

Try this Try this

`[scroll setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];`

And your Maximum zoom scale is strange. Try with 2,0 to test.

Comment: Okay. The contentSize should be the UIImageview size, not the ScrollView size.